# How to perform double mouse click action in blueprism

Tags: click, double, mouse, blueprism

I am facing trouble for performing mouse double click action, the element can spied in UI/AA modes but I couldn't find a way how to perform double click action.  Hope somebody will help me on this.

Thanks
Satya Srinivas

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Navigate stage to action your spied element, you should have a "Click Centre" and also a "Double Click Centre" action available under the Action column of the Action tab; unless maybe you are trying to do this with the root element (the one at top of list) in which case you will not see mouse click options.